# Relational properties preserved under quotients

Tags: logic, relations, quotient-spaces

Suppose R is a binary relation on a non-empty set S. Let E be an equivalence relation on S. Now form the obvious quotient structure: Let S' be the set of all E-equivalence classes [s] of members s of S, and let R' be the binary relation on S' for which [s]R'[t] if and only if sRt, whenever s and t are in S.

Clearly some properties of R are preserved by taking quotients in this way, while others aren't. For example, transitivity of R entails transitivity of R', but irreflexivity of R does not entail irreflexivity of R'.

Is there a general characterization of the properties of R that are preserved under this quotient construction?

Comment: are you thinking a quotient-ring ?

Comment: No, I don't want to assume any structure on S other than an arbitrary binary relation R. The problem seems so elementary that there must be some kind of answer...

Comment: ![type of magma][1][1]:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Magma_to_group2.svg

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee A relation is not an operation.

Comment: Sorry I still confuse the two as functions are a type of relation.

Comment: @Hoyt Your definition of $R'$ is not very clear. Let $R$ be the identity relation on $S=\{0,1\}$. Let $E$ be the equivalence relation on $S$ that identifies everything, i.e. $E=S\times S$. Your definition of $R'$ makes it sound like $[0]R'[1]$ is equivalent to $0R1$, i.e. $0=1$ and thus false, but since $[1]=[0]$ we have $[0]R'[0]$ is equivalent to $0=0$ which is true producing a contradiction. I think you want something more like: $XR'Y$ if and only if there exists an $s,t\in S$ such that $X=[s]$, $Y=[t]$, and $sRt$.

Comment: @Derek Elkins: You are right, the problem is ill-posed. My apologies.

Comment: You can edit it.

Comment: If [r]R'[s], [t]R'[u] and [s] = [t], prove [r]R'[u] or withdraw your claim that transitivity is  preserved.

Comment: @ William Elliot and @ Roddy MacPhee: I'm withdrawing both the question and all claims made, since the relation R' is ill-defined.

Answer (score 0):

A well defined R' is
[a]R'[b] when exists x in [a], y in [b] with xRy.

If R is reflexive, symmetrical or total,
then R is reflexive, symmetrical or total, respectively.

Other relational properties based upon assuming two instances of the relation require additional assumptions for preservation under quotients.